# How to set a delay in VB Script to let Excel update data

Tags: excel, vbscript, database-connection, updates, vba

I have an Excel file that automatically loads the data from an external database (via a Data Connection to an Accesss database that is, in turn, linked to a Sharepoint table). I need to automate the process of:

- opening the Excel file
- waiting for the data to refresh
- running a macro (in this file)
- closing the file

The script that I have is:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("excel spreadsheet.xlsm")
WScript.Sleep 1000 * 60 * 5
objExcel.Run "macro_name"
objWorkbook.close False
objExcel.Application.Quit
```

However, no matter what delay I set in WScript.sleep, it does not update the data; instead, it runs the macro on the data already in the spreadsheet. Could anyone help, please!

---

SOLUTION

In the end (and with the benefit of a few days' live testing), the following seems to be the cleanest and most efficient:

1. Removing the "WScript.Sleep 1000 * 60 * 5" line from the VB script altogether
2. In Excel, clearing "Enable Background Refresh" checkbox in Properties for each connection
3. Adding the following line to the macro before the main code

   ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

Many thanks to Philip and Santosh for the answers below pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your workbook you need to refresh the data in your QueryTables before you run you code.

Why not call the [Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197503.aspx) method on the querytable, at the beginning of your excel vba macro?

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot, added

    Range("Table_ExternalData_15").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

and it seems to work.
Will test it from the VB script overnight.

Answer (score 3):

For Excel-VBA you can use any one of the below to pause the code.

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

OR

```
Private Sub delay(seconds As Long)
    Dim endTime As Date
    endTime = DateAdd("s", seconds, Now())
    Do While Now() < endTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

or

```
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5))
```

---

sample code 
(will pause for 10 seconds)

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("excel spreadsheet.xlsm")
objExcel.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0,10))
objExcel.Run "macro_name"
objWorkbook.close False
objExcel.Application.Quit
```

Comment: I think the OP might need to force a refresh of the querytable programmatically before calling his macro, or, alternatively, modify the macro in Excel VBA (if available) to referesh, then call `Application.Wait TimeSerial ...`

Comment: @Philip i feel like the 3rd step (•running a macro ) occurs before the data required is available. Not very sure.

Comment: agree, adding a refresh line to the macro seems easiest. Setting BackgroundQuery to FALSE should take care of the order of data updating / rest of macro running. Will report tomo or in a few days as the source database changes. @ Santosh: From my past experience with Excel, Application.Wait did not work very well with queries (at least Bloomberg ones). Can't comment on #1 and #2 options - but thanks in any case!

Comment: @r-q When you create object of application`Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`
then you have to apply wait as `objExcel.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0,10))`. Do try & let us know. Thanks